# Method returning wrong value

Tags: java, swing, date, methods

I'm creating a program that receives the current date and s tomorrow's date. Everything was working fine but when I tried entering the day 30 for the 4TH month, instead of taking it as the last day of the month and going to the next month, it just added one more day and returned 31. I later found out that the method that sets the maximum day for each month was returning the maximum day as 0. When I try putting the code from the method into

```
actionPerformed
```

it works fine but in the method i made it keeps returning maximum day as zero, i've tried using different variables and other things but nothing's working.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tomorrow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JLabel dayL;
JLabel monthL;
JLabel yearL;
JTextField dayT;
JTextField monthT;
JTextField yearT;
JButton enter;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tomorrow frame=new Tomorrow();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocation(500, 300);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Enter Current Date");
}

void createGUI(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window=getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout(5));

    dayL=new JLabel("Enter the day for today's date");
    window.add(dayL);
    dayT=new JTextField(10);
    window.add(dayT);
    monthL=new JLabel("Enter the month for today's date");
    window.add(monthL);
    monthT=new JTextField(10);
    window.add(monthT);
    yearL=new JLabel("Enter the year for today's date");
    window.add(yearL);
    yearT=new JTextField(10);
    window.add(yearT);
    enter=new JButton("Enter");
    window.add(enter);
    enter.addActionListener(this);
}

int maxiDay(int month, int day, int year){
    if((month==1)||(month==3)||(month==5)||(month==7)||(month==8)||(month==10)||(month==12)){
            day=31;
    }else if((month==4)||(month==6)||(month==9)||(month==11)){
            day=30;
    }else if(month==2){
        if((year%400==0)||(year%100!=0&&year%4==0)){
            if(day>28){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Highest day for this month is 28");
            day=28;
            }
        }else{
            if(day>29){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Highest day for this month is 29");
                day=29;
            }
        }
    }
    return day;
}

int todDay;
int todMonth;
int todYear;
int tomDay;
int tomMonth;
int tomYear;
int maxDay;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ((!dayT.getText().isEmpty())||(!monthT.getText().isEmpty())||(!yearT.getText().isEmpty())){
    todDay=Integer.parseInt(dayT.getText());
    todMonth=Integer.parseInt(monthT.getText());
    todYear=Integer.parseInt(yearT.getText());
    }
    maxiDay(todMonth, maxDay, todYear);
    if(todDay>maxDay){
        if(maxDay==31){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Highet day for this month is 31");
            todDay=31;
        }else if(maxDay==30){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Highet day for this month is 30");
            todDay=30;
            }
    }

    if(todDay==maxDay){
        tomDay=1;
        tomMonth=todMonth+1;
    }else if((todMonth==12)&&(todDay==31)){
        tomDay=1;
        tomMonth=1;
        tomYear=todYear+1;
    }
    tomDay=todDay+1;
    tomMonth=todMonth;
    tomYear=todYear;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "(DD/MM/YYYY)" + "\nTomorrow's date is: " + tomDay + "/" + tomMonth + "/" + tomYear + maxDay);
}

}
```

I just really need to know what I'm doing wrong
P.S I can't get rid of the method I made and put in actionPerformed, it's an assignment and it has to be done that way.

Comment: Where do you assign the value of maxDay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You haven't stored the return value from the function

```
maxiDay(todMonth, maxDay, todYear);
```

2.You are using another variable named 'maxDay' to compare which is not initialised.

```
if(todDay>maxDay){
    if(maxDay==31){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Highet day for this month is 31");
        todDay=31;
    }else if(maxDay==30){
```

It should be

```
maxDay = maxiDay(todMonth, maxDay, todYear);
if(todDay>maxDay){
 if(maxDay == 31)....
```

Answer (score 0):

You must store the returned value of `maxiDay(todMonth, maxDay, todYear);` in proper variable.

`maxiDay` method is changing the local value of the `day` parameter. Outside of `maxiDay` such changes will not exist.

Indeed it makes no sense to pass `maxDay` to `maxiDay` because it is an uninitialized variable that is not being changed. In java parameter passing is made by value, i. e., you are passing to the method `maxiDay` a copy of the value of the `maxDay` variable and then inside of `maxiDay` you are modifying that copy, not the original variable.